# htaccess rewrite when image doesn't exist, all others go to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to accomplish the following.

If an image is called from any folder and any sub-level deep, and it doesn't exist, then redirect it to a different folder.  (depts/misc/{filename}).

If any other file is called in any folder and any sub-levels deep, and it exists, process it.  If it doesn't exist, redirect it to index.php.

Below is what I have, and the index.php is processing fine, however the image that isn't found returns a 404.

```
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(png|jpe?g|gif))$ depts/misc/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your rules in the wrong order. You need to process the non-existent image first, before you process a non-existent anything else:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(png|jpe?g|gif))$ depts/misc/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Besides that, `%{REQUEST_URI}` will never match `^\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$`. The first `^` needs to be removed, like so: `\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$`, or the entire condition can be removed, as it is already tested in the rewriterule itself.